# Parsing Particular .Cs file using Style-cop

Tags: stylecop

How can i parse a particular .Cs file using Style-cop .Net code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you intend to do with the parse tree?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CsParser class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Development/StyleCop/Microsoft/StyleCop/CSharp/CsParser.cs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file in VS and select Run StyleCop. Or are you trying to embed StyleCop into an app?